# Build Failed in ios react native

Tags: xcode, react-native, build, product, archive

i'm trying to upload app on the test flight and i'm doing Product > Archive. but it always gives me the error Shell Script Invocation Error Group
InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//UPPCL.app/Frameworks/DoubleConversion.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Here is the attach photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlX4d.png)

Comment: Have you solve this? we have a similar issue.